# How to recover passphrase

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have generated my public key with passphrase by the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "joy@example.com"
```

But problem is that I have forgotten it. Now whenever I am going to git push my code it asks for my password. Is there any way I can recover it? Otherwise I have to regenerate it from scratch.

Comment: The point of a secret passphrase is that it cannot be regenerated or guessed. If it's really important and you have time and money to spend, a brute-force guessing attack could be feasible, but you should probably just swallow and start over.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover a passphrase out of a public or private key (unless with an extreme large cluster).

Furthermore you cannot really regenerate the key from scratch since the key took as input the passphrase. And a hash of the passphrase is somehow encoded in the keypair.

What you can do is generate a new key (with a new passphrase), set your ssh-agent to use the new key by default. You will however need access to server to copy the new key to.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing automation today and accidentally misspelled one of my passphrases. I just knew I blindly wrote letters in wrong order and couldn't find out how from retyping on keyboard. Thus I cracked it with python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from itertools import permutations
from subprocess import Popen

# bruteforce misspelled passphrase
for psph in ["ps%d"% "".join(i) for i in permutations("aswor")]:
    cmd = "ssh-keygen -p -f \"/home/m-nikolaev/.ssh/id_rsa\" -P \"%s\"" % psph
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    p.wait()
```

Sixth permutation showed I messed up four adjacent keys.